# name of the process of heating butter to give it the special aroma

Tags: frying, butter

One of common toppings for fruit pierogi and several other dishes, usually sweet, is butter that has been melted and heated on a skillet/saucepan until it got a somewhat deeper golden color, and a special unique aroma and flavor.

What is this process called?

(I believe it's also the first phase of preparing clarified butter, but I'm not sure about that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called browned butter or beurre noisette.  It is essentially heating butter beyond its melting point until the solids start to darken.  E.g.: a recipe is [here at Kitchn.](https://www.thekitchn.com/basic-techniques-how-to-brown-77018)

Comment: There would not be solids in melted butter.

Comment: "Milk solids" refers to the proteins and other dissolved solids in the water phase of milk and butter. If you took that liquid butter, for example, and filtered it under vacuum, your filter paper would be left coated with a solid white powder, mostly casein (of course it would be brown if you browned the butter first).